# ConfigParser with Custom Dict Type

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I need to create a custom ConfigParser which adds a few features including, most relevantly here, a default value for unset keys of None.  This seems to be supported through custom dict types and accordingly I wrote something like this:

```
class SyncDict(collections.UserDict):
  ...
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    if key in self.data:
      return self.data[key]
    return None
  ...

class SyncConfig(ConfigParser):
  ...
  def __init__(self, filename):
    super().__init__(allow_no_value=True, dict_type = SyncDict)
  ...
```

However, this does not work as it still raises KeyError in SectionProxy.  For example,

```
>>> a = SyncConfig('aaa.cfg')
>>> a.add_section('b')
>>> b = a['b']
>>> b['c']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\configparser.py", line 1254, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'c'
```

Am I missing something, or this really not supposed to be possible?

PS: Bonus points for a way to make SyncDict return a value of an empty SyncDict when asked for a section and None when asked for an option.

Comment: Use the `get` method instead. It already returns `None`  for a section proxy, and then you don't even need to define the dict nor the parser: `b.get('c)`